# Is it possible to restrict client-to-client communication on a switch?

Tags: networking, firewall, switch, vlan, traffic

I have a linux machine acting as a router with a wifi interface (hostapd) and multiple ethernet interfaces bridged together. I want to add multiple smart home devices to the network.

What I am trying to achieve is to restrict client-to-client communication between all devices (LAN and WLAN). Communication should only be allowed through (L2) firewalling on the linux machine.

Therefore to disable intra-BSS switching on the WLAN interface I activated `ap_isolate=1` in hostapd which forwards the packets to the router. This works just fine.
Working with discrete LAN interfaces for every device should also work.

However, the problem I am currently facing is that I don't know how to restrict client-to-client communication on the router when there is a (managed) switch involved on one of the ethernet ports (see the picture below).
Many smart home apps require the smartphone and the devices to be on the same network. Therefore the use of VLANs would not be feasible.

Would port isolation on the switch work for my problem? I am thinking about only allowing traffic from the devices to the router and vice versa (P2<->P1, P3<->P1). Traffic between devices should then be blocked on the switch. Would communication still be possible when it is explicitly allowed on the firewall? Would this setup have any drawbacks?

[image: Communication should be through the firewall]

Comment: A "normal" switch is a dumb networking device. What you want is a either a "managed" switch or router, and potentially one that has VLANs to create separate networks for each port.

Comment: @Mokubai by "switch" i meant both, managed and unmanaged switches whatever is more suitable. I want to avoid using VLANs as all smart home devices would be on a different network. This would make it difficult to communicate with them through their smartphone apps as they often expect the devices to be on the same network.